# Android. How to get dimensions of visible part of image

Tags: java, android, image, android-imageview

I have a ImageView. Actually it's an ImageViewTouch - an image which can be zoomed panned etc. I need to get dimensions of a visible part of zoomed/panned image So I can later cut out the visible part of image.

Answer (score -1):

getGlobalVisibleRect does what you want.

Comment: getGlobalVisibleRect only returns the position and dimensions of the View (in my case ImageViewTouch) on screen.